# Line bundles on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth,  complex, projective, algebraic curve of genus $g$ and $L$ be a line bundle on it. Let $K$ be the canonical bundle. We have  the Riemann-Roch theorem for line bundles on curves :

$h^0(X,L) - h^0(X, L^{-1} \otimes K) = \text{deg}(L) +1 -g$.

Let's assume that $\text{deg}(L^{-1} \otimes K)$ is known(let's say it's a positive number). At this point my question is the following :

Is it possible to obtain an inequality of the following form: $\text{deg}(L) < h^0(L) +$ some number which comes from the already known information?

reversing the role of $L$ and $L^{-1}\otimes K$ we obtain $\text{deg}(L) = 2g-2 + \text{deg}(L^{-1}\otimes K)$. But I am unable to see how $h^0(L)$ enters into the picture.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: You mean like $\deg(L)=h^0(L)+g-1-h^0(L^{-1}\otimes K)<h^0(L)+g$? If you want a less trivial inequality, you should be more specific, what it is you need.

Comment: @Ben, Can we obtain a more refined upperbound where the term other than $h^0(L)$ is less than $g$ using the information $\text{deg}(L^{-1} \otimes K)$?.

Comment: What do you need the inequality for anyways? If you know $ \deg(L^{-1}\otimes K)$ and $g$, then you know $\deg(L)$; are you looking for a lower bound on $h^0(L)$?

Comment: @Ben, I was trying to figure out whether, from $\text{deg}(L^{-1} \otimes K) (>0)$, we can say something more specific about $h^0((L^{-1} \otimes K)$ and therefore obtaining a more refined upperbound. Can we say anything specific when $C$ is a plane curve of degree $d$?